# eclipselink IndirectCollectionsProvider points to JDK 8 in Weblogic 12c/JDK 7

Tags: eclipselink, weblogic12c

I got the following error when I'm running in the following environment:

- Weblogic 12c
- JDK 7
- Eclipselink 2.6.0

Is this a bug to be reported to Eclipselink development?

```
####<Apr 6, 2015 7:17:19 PM SGT> <Error> <Class Loaders> <ISPS-APP> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1428319039472> <BEA-2162500> <Class, org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.jdk8.IndirectCollectionsProvider, was compiled with an incompatible version of Java. Make sure that all the classes needed by the application have been compiled with a compatible java version. java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/indirection/jdk8/IndirectCollectionsProvider : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/persistence/internal/indirection/jdk8/IndirectCollectionsProvider : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
```

## Update 07-Apr-2015:

Here is the stacktrace https://gist.github.com/mallim/0a6ffcd9ec9a8b923fbd

Take note that no such error encountered when I revert back to Eclipselink 2.5.3RC1

## Update 22-Apr-2015:

The bug is reported here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=464096

Comment: Can you provide more of the stack trace?  When are you seeing that issue, is it an exception in your application or just something appearing in the logs?

Comment: This is an error which occurs with Eclipselink 2.6.0 once I switch back to Eclipselink 2.5.3RC1, the error does not occur anymore. Let me try and find back the error log and put it here..

Comment: @IanLim I have the very same issue running Jersey 2.23.1 in JBoss 7.1.1 since jersey-media-moxy depends on org.eclipse.persistence.moxy 2.6.0. Do you know which is the next version with java 7?

Answer (score 0):

best would be to file a bug (at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink) , provide steps to reproduce (ie how did you update EclipseLink - is it just part of your app or did you modify your WLS installation somehow? is JDK 8 on your servers path somewhere?) and attach some simple app for reproducing the issue there.